# ‘Jenkinsfile’ not found

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I try to use Jenkinsfile for executing build.ps1 file. However, when I scan multibranch-pipeline, I see `Does not meet criteria` log. Why Jenkins cannot find file. My repo url is [this](https://github.com/AdemCatamak/Practices/tree/jenkins-tutorial).

Jenkins version : 2.138.3

Jenkinsfile is:

```
#!groovy

node {
  stage ('Checkout') {
    checkout scm
  }

  stage('Check Env Parameters'){
    echo "Branch Name : ${env.GIT_BRANCH}"
    echo "Octo Server Address : ${env.octoServer}"
  }

  stage('Run Cake') {
    powershell -File build.ps1 -projectName="Jenkins_PowerShell_Cake_Tutorial" -branchName=${env.GIT_BRANCH} -octoServer=${env.octoServer} -octoApiKey=${env.octoApiKey}
  }
}
```

Jenkinsfile's type is not txt

[image: Jenkinsfile file type screenshoot]

Jenkin Log:

[image: Jenkins Log]

Jenkins Configuration : 
[image: project configuration]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Jenkinsfile` in your repo is named `.Jenkinsfile` (with a dot as first character). Either rename the file or configure the script path with the dot.

Comment: Thanks so much. VsCode shows icon for `.Jenkinsfile`. When I convert it to `Jenkinsfile`, icon is gone. This issue confuses me.

Answer (score 0):

Check Jenkinsfile path if not on the same level provide a relative path. This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a bug in Jenkins related to this issue:
https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-54126